# Exception while reading RDS secrets from AWS secrets manager using aws-secretsmanager-jdbc

Tags: amazon-web-services, c3p0, aws-secrets-manager, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am using AWS SDK for java on my project and now want to use the AWS secrets manager to store RDS details. while integrating `aws-secretsmanager-jdbc`, getting a below error while running a query against database:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SERVICE_ID
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.executeDescribeSecret(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:885)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.describeSecret(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:866)
    at com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.caching.cache.SecretCacheItem.executeRefresh(SecretCacheItem.java:102)
    at com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.caching.cache.SecretCacheItem.executeRefresh(SecretCacheItem.java:32)
    at com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.caching.cache.SecretCacheObject.refresh(SecretCacheObject.java:188)
    at com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.caching.cache.SecretCacheObject.getSecretValue(SecretCacheObject.java:286)
    at com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.caching.SecretCache.getSecretString(SecretCache.java:123)
    at com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerDriver.connectWithSecret(AWSSecretsManagerDriver.java:321)
    at com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerDriver.connect(AWSSecretsManagerDriver.java:384)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

I did some research and found out that this might be the version conflict issue between `sdk-core` and `secretsmanager`. Here is the maven dependency tree:

```
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:secretsmanager:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-json-protocol:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:protocol-core:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:auth:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:regions:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:apache-client:jar:2.10.30:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- software.amazon.awssdk:netty-nio-client:jar:2.10.30:runtime
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws.secretsmanager:aws-secretsmanager-jdbc:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws.secretsmanager:aws-secretsmanager-caching-java:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager:jar:1.11.418:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.281:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.281:compile
[INFO] +- software.amazon.awssdk:secretsmanager:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-json-protocol:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:protocol-core:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:auth:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:regions:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core:jar:2.10.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:apache-client:jar:2.10.30:runtime
[INFO] |  \- software.amazon.awssdk:netty-nio-client:jar:2.10.30:runtime
[INFO] \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.281:compile
[INFO]    \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.281:compile
```

FYI, I am using bom file for AWS JAVA SDK and that has version **2.5.47** while `aws-secretsmanager-jdbc` have AWS JAVA SDK version **1.11.418**

I am trying to use AWS wrapper to connect with database [AWS Secrets Manager JDBC](https://github.com/aws/aws-secretsmanager-jdbc)

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: 'I did some research and found out that this might be the version conflict issue between sdk-core and secretsmanager.'     Wait how did you determine this was a version conflict issue? The error message doesn't give such an indication

Comment: @committedandroider Googled for `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SERVICE_ID' and this error happened with other AWS services and I found threads mentioning that this is a service issue with aws-sdk-core version as it is being used by aws services and sometimes there is a mismatch with the service and core version

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't pay attention to the name of the field - SERVICE_ID. That's telling

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out, its the issue happening because of the wrong version of the core library. I was trying to use AWS SDK 2.x and 1.x in the same project so I had this version conflict.

Fixed by adding versions to pom as below:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.418</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmespath-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.418</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.418</version>
        </dependency>
```